# Is there a Python equivalent of Matlab's potential(V, X, Y) function

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, scipy

Is there a library in python that provides the same functionality as Matlab's [*potential*(*V*,*X*)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.potential.html#d126e277721) function, which inverts a 3D or 2D gradient into a scalar potential surface?

I've tried a couple of brute-force methods to "integrate" over two U and V vectors to get a Z surface, but all have been very unsatisfactory, missing obvious "peaks and troughs" indicated by the vector field.

Comment: can you give an example of what ```potential(V, X)``` does? Does it perform something similar to [this](https://github.com/yqueau/normal_integration) Matlab package for normal integration?

Comment: Potential in MATLAB symbolically solves a vector pair into a single potential surface unfortunately having just gotten Matlab [re]installed the equation pair is not responding well there [the "model" is u(x,y)=a x^4 + b y^4 + c and v(x,y)=d x^4 + e y^4 + f].  I'm presently working through UrBoiRAD's more brute force (which is similar to other recommendations I've seen in StackOverflow when I get breaks to troubleshoot it but it but I'm having difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scipy specifically the scipy.integrate module

An Example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import simps

# Define your 3D or 2D gradient field
grad = np.array([U, V, W]) # Replace U, V, W with your own data

# Compute the scalar potential surface
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(grad.shape[1]), np.arange(grad.shape[0]), np.arange(grad.shape[2]))
potential = np.zeros_like(grad)
for i in range(grad.shape[0]):
    for j in range(grad.shape[1]):
        for k in range(grad.shape[2]):
            potential[i,j,k] = simps(simps(simps(grad[:i+1,:j+1,:k+1], z[:k+1], axis=2), y[:j+1], axis=1), x[:i+1], axis=0)

# The potential surface is stored in the 'potential' variable
```

Comment: Is this an AI generated answer?

Comment: @mozway No the code is a modified version from some example code in the documentation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/integrate.html) should have linked it thats on me.